# Flink streaming: how to control the execution time

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Spark streaming provides API for termination awaitTermination().  Is there any similar API available to gracefully shut down flink streaming after some t seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Your driver program (i.e. the `main` method) in Flink doesn't stay running while the streaming job executes.   Your program should define a dataflow, call `execute`, and then terminate.   In Spark, the driver program stays running (AFAIK), and `awaitTermination` relates to that.

Note that a Flink streaming dataflow continues to execute indefinitely, unless you're using a 'bounded' data source with a finite number of elements.  You may also cancel or stop a job, and even take a checkpoint upon stopping to be resumed from later.