# How to stop after reading a few messages from Kafka in Flink Scala Shell?

Tags: scala, shell, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm reading messages from Kafka into the Flink Scala shell. I want to read a few messages, store them and stop. Don't want to keep reading continuously. I'm able to read the messages as follows :

```
scala> val stream = senv.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer011[String]("some-test-topic", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties)).print()
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
stream: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSink[String] = org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSink@3ba8ef4e

scala> senv.execute("Kafka Consumer Test")
Submitting job with JobID: 79b7380516b8ccb9ae71da29c97c8d8d. Waiting for job completion.
Connected to JobManager at Actor[akka.tcp://flink@localhost:55677/user/jobmanager#2006479320] with leader session id 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.
03/12/2019 15:15:16 Job execution switched to status RUNNING.
03/12/2019 15:15:16 Source: Custom Source -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to SCHEDULED 
03/12/2019 15:15:16 Source: Custom Source -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to DEPLOYING 
03/12/2019 15:15:16 Source: Custom Source -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to RUNNING
```

I'm not able to stop reading messages without exiting the entire shell. When I press `Ctrl-C`, it kills the job as well as the shell. How can I time the process, so that it reads a few messages and stops itself after some time? Is it possible to kill it while it's running, without exiting the shell?

Comment: Maybe this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330102/flink-streaming-how-to-control-the-execution-time

Comment: It says that the Flink program should terminate after calling execute. So, is it not possible to capture only a few messages and stop?

Comment: @SoheilPourbafrani - Can you please also have a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128833/how-to-deserialize-avro-messages-from-kafka-in-flink-scala ?